# Prompts user to publish feed with PHP SDK

Tags: facebook-graph-api, dialog, facebook-php-sdk

Sorry for my English, I'll try to explain my problem.

With this code I can publish feed on the wall of the users without prompts (I need extended permissions..)

```
        $ret_obj = $facebook->api('/me/feed', 'POST',
                                array(
                                  'link' => 'www.example.com',
                                  'message' => 'Posting with the PHP SDK!'
                             ));
```

But How can I use PHP SDK to prompts the user to publish as can be done with this code (using Javascript SDK)

```
    <script src='http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js'></script>
<p><a onclick='postToFeed(); return false;'>Post to Feed</a></p>
<p id='msg'></p>

<script> 
  FB.init({appId: "YOUR_APP_ID", status: true, cookie: true});

  function postToFeed() {

    // calling the API ...
    var obj = {
      method: 'feed',
      link: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/',
      picture: 'http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg',
      name: 'Facebook Dialogs',
      caption: 'Reference Documentation',
      description: 'Using Dialogs to interact with users.'
    };

    function callback(response) {
      document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = "Post ID: " + response['post_id'];
    }

    FB.ui(obj, callback);
  }

</script>
```

Thanks to all!

Comment: Which part exactly are you having troubles with? Adding more fields?

Comment: My probem is that with the PHP SDK code my app. publish the feed on the user wall without the dialog popup, I need to prompts users to publish. (The Javascript SDK Example do it!)

Answer (score 0):

Seems you will need to `cUrl` the dialog end point to get the effect you desire.
I would suggest using a button or link and opening a new page which will cUrl the endpoint and redirect back to that page with a close tab or page button.

example endpoint link https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=135669679827333&link=https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/&picture=http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg&name=Facebook%20Dialogs&caption=Reference%20Documentation&description=Using%20Dialogs%20to%20interact%20with%20users.&redirect_uri=http://anotherfeed.com/?pid=facebook

---

Refer to: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/#display

---

### examples:  under construction.

```
<?php
require 'facebook.php';
// Create our application instance
// (replace this with your appId and secret).
$app_id = "APP_ID";
$secret = "APP_SECRET";
$app_url = "APP_URL";

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => $app_id,
  'secret' => $secret,
  'cookie' => true,
));

// Get User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();
if ($user) {
  try {
    // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
  } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    error_log($e);
    $user = null;
  }
    $access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();

}    
?>
```